# Queryset object

Tags: python, django

How to create query set object when work with custom query.

i want to join 5 table. but there is no foreign key defined in all table (its integer field instead of Foreign key)

Example : PersonID is integer field. That store id of user . So now i want to join this both table as no foreign key defined. So how to join this two.

And if we used custom query like

```
 cursor.connection()
 cursor.execute()
```

Then its not retrieve query set object . I need query set object in anyhow. So can you please help me out from this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`raw()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/) query:

```
Person.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM app_person <YOUR JOINS HERE>")
```

**UPDATE**: If you want the docts with values instead of model instances then you could use [direct SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) instead of `QuerySet` manipulation.  The recipe is described in the docs:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return [dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
           for row in cursor.fetchall()]

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM app_person <YOUR JOINS HERE>");
values =  dictfetchall(cursor)
```

Comment: its give me row queryset. I want values that is in Queryset object. Thanks